# Join multiple tables to return only one result for each record from main table

Tags: sql, hive

Currently I have three tables I am joining.  I have data that was migrated from one system(old) to another system(new).  I need to compare this data to ensure matches but also mismatches.  I have three tables. One has the list of accounts being moved.  The two systems have differnt ID types so this first table is a list of all IDs for the two tables and each account that was moved.  So this is my base population.

```
ID1 ID2
ABC 123
ABC 123
ABC 123
DEF 456
DEF 456
DEF 456
```

I then have table 2 which is all the data from the old system.

```
ID  Fname   Lname
ABC John    Smith
ABC Tom Smith
ABC Kate    Smith
DEF Jason   Thomas
DEF Ruby    Thomas
DEF Alex    Johnson
```

Then table 3 is all the data found in the new system.

```
ID  Fname   Lname
123 John    Smith
123 Tom Smith
123 Kate    Smith
456 Jason   Thomas
456 Ruby    Thomas
```

Right now when I join these tables on the ID I get a lot more rows than I need.

When I do my join I receive this:

```
ID  Fname_old   Lname_old   ID2 Fname_new   Lname_new
ABC John    Smith   123 John    Smith
ABC John    Smith   123 Tom Smith
ABC John    Smith   123 Kate    Smith
```

I am trying to join them where it only returns the row that matches, and if it can't find a match I should still get the ID from the ID file and the data from table 2(old data) as this is the data that was sent to the new system.

```
ID1 ID2 Fname_old   Lname_old   Fname_new   Lname_new
ABC 123 John    Smith   John    Smith
ABC 123 Tom Smith   Tom Smith
ABC 123 Kate    Smith   Kate    Smith
DEF 456 Jason   Thomas  Jason   Thomas
DEF 456 Ruby    Thomas  Ruby    Thomas
DEF 456 Alex    Johnson
```

The code I am using is:

```
Select a.ID1, a.ID2, b.fname as fname_old, b.lnam as lname_old, 
c.fname as fname_new, c.lname as lname_new
from table1 a
left join table2 b
on a.ID1 = b.ID
left join table3 c
on a.ID2 = c.ID
```

Comment: Your tables are strange. A table's ID should identify a row, hence the name. Your tables, however, have duplicate IDs. That's a bad idea, as you have probably noticed by now.

Comment: Without unique IDs, you join on the ID pairs in the ID table. There are multiple pairs of 123/ABC and you join 123/John/Smith with ABC/John/Smith and 123/Tom/Smith with ABC/Tom/Smith and say there are no changes. If I join on IDs only, however, I could just as well join 123/John/Smith with ABC/Tom/Smith and 123/Tom/Smith with ABC/John/Smith and say John changed to Tom and Tom to John. So, you are silently applying rules that are not in your query. It seems you want some iteration: find unchanged rows first, then see what remains and guess which record changed into which other by closeness.

Comment: … and this is something that you may want to do outside the DBMS. I.e. select all rows that have no perfect match and then iterate through them in a programming langauge. With 789/Betty/Jones before and XYZ/Betty/Miller and XYZ/Mandy/Jones afterwards, was Betty changed to Mandy or Jones changed to Miller or was Betty Jones removed and  Betty Miller and Mandy Jones added? You must make up the rules and apply them. This is no task for SQL.

Comment: The ID in this case is the ID number for the account.  These are two seperate systems that we are switching too.  We have an old system that uses flat files to send data.  We then have our new system which is based on a JSON format that is ingesting those flat files and applying processes too.  So I am trying to compare the accounts in the flatfiles to ensure the accoutn details in the JSON files was carried over and processed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If its just duplicate rows in your first table you could try distincting them in a derived table like below:

```
Select a.ID1, a.ID2, b.fname as fname_old, b.lnam as lname_old, 
c.fname as fname_new, c.lname as lname_new
from (SELECT DISTINCT ID1, ID2 FROM table1) a
left join table2 b
on a.ID1 = b.ID
left join table3 c
on a.ID2 = c.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You are joining them on ID columns.

ID columns are usually UNIQUE while you have multiple identical IDs and specify join on those IDs.

Since you need to compare data, i suggest you lookup MATCH and how it works as that seems to be closer to what you are looking for here.

Comment: Yes, for some of the records there is only one ID which makes it easier, I was having the issue when there is multiple instnacse of the same ID with different data within the other fields that need to be compared.  Thank you for the suggestion I will look up MATCH and see if that will better serve.

Answer (score 0):

You can get *a* match using `row_number()`:

```
Select a.ID1, a.ID2, b.fname as fname_old, b.lnam as lname_old, 
c.fname as fname_new, c.lname as lname_new
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from table1 a
     ) a left join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from table2 b
     ) b
     on a.ID1 = b.ID and a.seqnum = b.seqnum
     (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from table3 c
     ) c
     on a.ID2 = c.ID and a.seqnum = c.seqnum;
```

Note:  This does not preserve the "ordering" of the original values, so any rows can be matched with any other.  Why?  **SQL tables represent unordered sets.**

If there is an ordering in the tables, you can use that in the `order by` clauses to get a match consistent with the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a compare chance for name and last name this code will work.

```
select DISTINCT a.ID1, a.ID2, b.fname as fname_old, b.lname as lname_old, c.fname as 
fname_new, c.lname as lname_new from table2 b
left join table1 a on a.ID1=b.ID 
left join table3 c on a.ID2=c.ID  and b.Fname=c.Fname and b.Lname=c.Lname
```

My Result :

```
ID1 ID2 fname_old   lname_old   fname_new   lname_new
ABC 123 John    Smith   John    Smith
ABC 123 Kate    Smith   Kate    Smith
ABC 123 Tom     Smith   Tom     Smith
DEF 456 Alex    Johnson NULL    NULL
DEF 456 Jason   Thomas  Jason   Thomas
DEF 456 Ruby    Thomas  Ruby    Thomas
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that this is data transferred to two systems. So you expect all data to match. You could hence reduce the query to only find data that doesn't match, if any.

Here is a SQL standard compliant query. You tagged your request with hive. I don't know about hive, so you may have to adjust the query.

```
select 
  t2.id as id1,
  t3.id as id2,
  t2.fname as fname_old,
  t2.lname as lname_old,
  t3.fname as fname_new,
  t3.lname as lname_new
from table2 t2
full outer join t3
   on t3.fname = t2.fname
  and t3.lname = t2.lname
  and exists (select null from table1 t1 where t1.id1 = t2.id and t1.id2 = t3.id)
where t2.id is null or t3.id is null;
```

This is a full anti join. It returns all rows that have no exact match in the other table. It doesn't, however guesstimate which deviating rows may be pairs. You will get a result like this:

```
ID1 | ID2 | Fname_old | Lname_old | Fname_new | Lname_new
----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------
DEF |     | Alex      | Johnson   |           |
GHI |     | Jone      | Miller    |           |
GHI |     | Maxx      | Miller    |           |
GHI |     | Fritz     | Miller    |           |
    | 789 |           |           | Joan      | Miller
    | 789 |           |           | Max       | Miller
    | 799 |           |           | Fritz     | Miller
```

As you see, you would have to examine this result manually. But ideally the query shouldn't return any row at all, which would just prove that everything went as expected and nobody (system or person) messed with the data :-)